# My laptop has saved all files to a class path. How do i remove it?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse and I had saved a file. however, all the projects have a classpath now. I don't know how this happened. Is there any way to remove it. this is how my files have all changed now:
[image: this is how my files have all changed now]

Comment: Since the "files" now also appear to consist of bin and src folders, I would check to see if my files are all gone now. Be very careful when clicking apply to all and okay in eclipse.

Comment: You may be looking at the _Navigator_ view instead of the _Project Explorer_ or _Package Explorer_. Please show the whole window.

Comment: A `.classpath` file just means your project is a Java project. It is not an error that it is created. Project/Package Explorer usually hide the .classpath and .project files but this can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

That belongs to the eclipse project configuration of a java project (like the .project) and you should not remove it.

BUT you can hide it from your view:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's an outdated Eclipse. Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).